# Assign value to a pointer of structure

Tags: c

I'm trying to assign value to `my_record` but the compiler keeps indicating that my line `my_record->x = counter;` is having an error:

> uninitialized local variable 'my_record' used.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct rec
{
    int x, y, z;
} *abc;

int main()
{
    int counter;
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    //struct rec my_record;
    abc my_record;

    ptr_myfile = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
    if (!ptr_myfile)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }
    for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
    {
        my_record->x = counter;
        fwrite(&my_record, sizeof(abc), 1, ptr_myfile);
    }
    fclose(ptr_myfile);
    system("pause");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never allocated any memory for `my_record` to point to. Why are you using a pointer instead of just a regular struct?

Comment: `abc my_record = malloc(sizeof *my_record);`

Comment: Also see [is it a good idea to typedef pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: Although it might not be obvious, in this code you loaded the gun, aimed precisely at your foot, and fired. `abc` is a random pointer, it's never initialized properly, and when you use it you're experiencing *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: It's important to understand that you have defined `abc` to be a type that is a pointer to `struct rec`s. That's why @tadman is saying that `my_record` is a random pointer.

Comment: It is a poor programming practice to hide pointers inside a typedef

Comment: The callable function: `system()` is exposed in the header file: `stdlib.`  However, the posted code is missing the `#include` statement for that header file.

Comment: Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the 'error' is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  One easy way to handle that operation is to call `perror( "your error message" );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems.

First, you didn't allocate memory for `my_record` to point to. The warning about using an uninitialized variable is because you didn't do:

```
abc my_record = malloc(sizeof(struct rec));
```

Second, the first argument to `fwrite()` should be the pointer to the structure you want to write, but you're using a pointer to the pointer.

Third, the second argument to `fwrite()` should be the size of the structure, but you're giving the size of the pointer.

There doesn't seem to be any good reason to define `abc` as a pointer in the first place. You should just declare a variable containing the structure itself.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct rec
{
    int x, y, z;
} abc;

int main()
{
    int counter;
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    //struct rec my_record;
    abc my_record;

    ptr_myfile = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
    if (!ptr_myfile)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }
    for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++)
    {
        my_record.x = counter;
        fwrite(&my_record, sizeof my_record, 1, ptr_myfile);
    }
    fclose(ptr_myfile);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of issues in your code like

- In this `abc my_record;` the `abc` is `struct rec*` and compiler is rightly complaining about `my_record` not being initialized. As it looks like

  `struct rec *my_record; /* un-initilized struct ptr */`

  So first allocate the memory for it like

  `abc my_record = malloc(sizeof(struct rec));`
- Here in `fwrite(&my_record, sizeof(abc), 1, ptr_myfile);` the second argument `sizeof(abc)` is wrong as `abc` is structure pointer, it won't yield in correct result. Also first arguement of `fwrite()` is wrong, as it should be pointer to structure `my_record` not `&my_record`.

  `fwrite(my_record, sizeof(struct rec), 1, ptr_myfile);`

And also you want to see [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) After reading this link you might want to avoid `typedef` a pointer as you did above in your code & you want to do like below

```
typedef struct rec {
    int x, y, z;
}abc;
int main(void) {
    int counter;
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    abc *my_record = malloc(sizeof(struct rec));
    ptr_myfile = fopen("test.bin", "wb");
    if (!ptr_myfile) {
        printf("Unable to open file!");
        return 1;
    }
    for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        my_record->x = counter;
        fwrite(my_record, sizeof(abc), 1, ptr_myfile);
    }
    fclose(ptr_myfile);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Include this
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct rec {
    int x, y, z;
} abc;

int main() {
    ...

    abc *my_record = (abc*) malloc( sizeof(abc) );

    ...
}
```